# Javascript - Compare 2 input split arrays and output the difference

Tags: arrays, compare

I have 2 inputs both containing a list of numbers separated by a '|'.
I need to check if any of the ids from the first input exist in the second and if it doesn't add it to a third.

```
<input type="text" id="access_ids" value="13|16|24|25|31|33|36|42|43|45|48|49|58|59|61|8" /><br />
<input type="text" id="replied_ids" value="8|9|16" /><br />
<input type="text" id="not_replied_ids" value="" />
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var acc_ids = $('#access_ids').text();
var acc_array = acc_ids.split('|');

for (var i = 0; i < acc_array.length; i++) {
    if (acc_array[i].indexOf($('#replied_ids')) > -1) {
        $('#not_replied_ids').text(acc_array[i].join('|'));
        return;
    }
}
```

});

I made a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sheferd/nhj63fbu/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong syntax, ex: `$('#access_ids').text()` --> `$('#access_ids').val()` ... You can try follow code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var acc_ids = $('#access_ids').val();
    var acc_array = acc_ids.split('|');
  var not_replied_arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < acc_array.length; i++) {
        if ($('#replied_ids').val().indexOf(acc_array[i]) == -1) {
            not_replied_arr.push(acc_array[i]);
            $("#not_replied_ids").val(not_replied_arr.join("|"));
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just had to remove the final return; That was making it output only the first result